# Syntax error at or near "IF" in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to write an sql function on PostgreSQL, but I have an error with the 'IF':

```
ERROR: Syntax error at or near "IF"
LINE 11: IF Type = 's' THEN
```

I can't understand the syntax error. 
(The Function without the IF work correctly)

My SQL Code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.add_activity(IDactivity smallint,Date_Start date, Data_End date, 
Type character varying,Name character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
Typology character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying, Client smallint DEFAULT NULL::smallint)
RETURNS void
LANGUAGE 'sql'
AS $BODY$

INSERT INTO public."Activity" 
VALUES(IDactivity, Date_Start, Data_End, Type, Name);

IF Type = 's' THEN
INSERT INTO public."Service" 
VALUES(IDactivity, Typology, Client); 

END IF;
$BODY$;
```

Thank you!

Comment: You cannot use `if` when you set the function language to SQL. You enable it using `LANGUAGE plpgsql`

Comment: @coladict thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IF` is not implemented in the `sql` language but it is in the `plpgsql` language, see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS).

You can either replace `LANGUAGE sql` by `LANGUAGE plpgsql` and then add `BEGIN` and `END` in the function body :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.add_activity(IDactivity smallint,Date_Start date, Data_End date, 
Type character varying,Name character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
Typology character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying, Client smallint DEFAULT NULL::smallint)
RETURNS void
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
INSERT INTO public."Activity" 
VALUES(IDactivity, Date_Start, Data_End, Type, Name);

IF Type = 's' THEN
INSERT INTO public."Service" 
VALUES(IDactivity, Typology, Client); 
END IF;

END ;
$BODY$
```

Or you can change your code to stay in the `sql` language :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.add_activity(IDactivity smallint,Date_Start date, Data_End date, 
Type character varying,Name character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
Typology character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying, Client smallint DEFAULT NULL::smallint)
RETURNS void
LANGUAGE sql
AS $BODY$

INSERT INTO public."Activity" 
VALUES(IDactivity, Date_Start, Data_End, Type, Name);

INSERT INTO public."Service"
SELECT IDactivity, Typology, Client
WHERE Type = 's' ;

$BODY$
```

Comment: I used the second version, it was much simpler than I thought. I feel stupid, but after 10 hours on the screen my brain disconnected :D